# The edit summary field is being treated as password field on Chrome for Android

Tags: bug, edit-summary, android

I'm on Chrome 110 on Android 10, and I'm seeing the key symbol indicating I'm in a password field when I'm on an edit summary field:

[image: key symbol on an edit summary field on a post on Sci-Fi Stack Exchange]

[image: key symbol on an edit summary field on a post on Stack Overflow]

That seems wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Mobile Chrome does this for all inputs regardless of whether or not they are `password` inputs. For example:

[image: Google image search showing key and credit card]

Mine also shows a credit card icon, though there is no case when I would need to use both a password and a saved credit card in the same field. I assume the reason these buttons is exist are for poorly programmed websites which don't automatically prompt for the relevant autofill.

You know it's not interpreting it as a `password` because you see plain text instead of "•••"

Comment: Ahh ok, not sure why I hadn't noticed it before - I doesn't do it for `textareas` otherwise you'd see it elsewhere as well....!

Comment: I do actually see it in textareas (such as this very answer!). However, I'm using iOS Chrome so there may be some differences.